# How to prevent reactivity on collection updates?

Tags: meteor

I want to update a document, but don't want all my reactive routes to reload (I use iron:router).

I cannot make all my `myCollection.find()` cursors non reactive (with `{reactive:false}`)

Wrapping the update in `Tracker.nonreactive` does not seem to work.

On the client:

```
Router.route '/spot/:shortName',
    template: 'map'
    onAfterAction: ->
        spot = Spots.findOne({shortName: this.params.shortName}, {reactive: false})
        Session.set('selectedSpot', spot)
```

On the server:

`Spots.update(spot._id, {$set: {codeIndex: codeIndex}})`

Comment: Do you update the document in a `minimongo`-only database or do you also update it on the server?

Comment: can you provide a bit more of your code?

Comment: @Kyll It is an update to minimongo but also propagated to the server.

Comment: Then that means you are publishing it? We need to see more of your code to understand how to solve your issue.

Comment: Just added above. The update is on the server not on minimongo.

Comment: Are you publishing this data? If you are, or if you are using `autopublish`, then I think it is what should be modified.

Comment: Yes it is. The client should react to updates of Spot. But not this particular update.